# Can I skip the tutorial in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I played through the tutorial mission on my first game of XCOM: Enemy Unknown, but I started here again when I played a second time. Is there any way to skip over it?

Comment: Just want to point out that while you lose some bonuses for skipping the tutorial, you also get to plan your base without mandatory tutorial placement of the lab and alien containment, meaning more money and time to get your satellites up

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is.  On the Select Difficulty screen, click the "Advanced Options" button to see a check box for this:

[image]

Once the tutorial has started, I don't believe there is any way to skip it besides quitting out and starting the game again.

Comment: I'll also point out that the tutorial is more than just the first mission - it's also some of what happens after you return to base for the first time.  If you played the demo's tutorial, running through the full game's might still be a good idea.

Comment: Any idea what the behavior is if you skip it? Does it automatically choose some research and base options for you as you may have had to choose during the tutorial, or do you start clean and fresh?

Comment: Skipping the tutorial allows you to choose from ALL base locations (not just NA & Euro), play the first mission without possibly losing the 3 units, and custom layout your base from the start.

Comment: @Anno sounds like a good reason to start a new game right after the tutorial

Comment: @Anno: by skipping tutorial you lose free satellite and the rewards for mission you start with are not as good as tutorial mission. You are likely to have more panic overall at the end of first month.